# Azure media player integration with Youtube and Vimeo

Tags: azure, youtube, media-player, vimeo

guys!
My question might be really dumb, but is it possible to playback Youtube and Vimeo URLs with Azure Media Player? 
As for now, I was able to play only manifest and mp4 URLs from my Azure Media Services account. But does it supports Youtube and Vimeo URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible using the AMP settings alone for the video element tag, but you can always have condition to use different settings on the video element on each platform.